# Measurability of Multivariate Functions and Coordinate Maps

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have some difficulties doing this problem:
Show that a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, x \mapsto (f_1(x), \ldots , f_m(x))$ is measurable
if, and only if, all coordinate maps $f_i : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,2,...,m$ are measurable.

In order to prove this, I can use:
Let $X$ be a set, let $(X_i, \mathcal{A}_i), i \in I$ be arbitrarily many measurable spaces, and let $T_i : X\rightarrow X_i$ be a family of maps. Show that a map $f$ from a measurable space $(F, \mathfrak{F})$ to $(X, \sigma(T_i : i \in I))$ is measurable if, and only if, all maps $T_i \circ f$ are $\mathfrak{F}/\mathcal{A}_i$-measurable.

Now my approach where I'm not sure if this makes sense:

Let's consider the projection map $P_{r_i}: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $P_{r_i}(x) = x_i$, where $i \in I = \{1, \ldots, m\}$ (the projections are the $T_i$'s). Then each $P_{r_i}$ is continuous. Hence, $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m) / \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable.
Thus, $\sigma(P_{r_1}, \ldots, P_{r_m}) \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m)$, and by the statement above, we get
$f : (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^m, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m))$ is measurable $\Leftrightarrow$  $P_{r_i} \circ f = f_i$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) / \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable for all $i \in I$.

Comment: Given  $f$ measurable and  $V\subset \mathbb R~$ open then $V\times \mathbb R\times \cdots \times \mathbb R$ borel set in $\mathbb R^n$ .Gives $f_1$ measurable.